# Checar se houve POST com Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Tenho uma aplicação singlepage, e gostaria de monitorar o POST para um webservice.

Quando eu fizer o envio da informação ele remover o loading.

ex:

```
scope.deleteFile = function (fileId,index) {
                scope.loading = true;
                imageHandler.remove(scope.contentId, fileId);
                scope.attachments.splice(index, 1);
            };
```

Esse foi o ponto onde parei, porém o `loading` ali está `true` e gostária de saber em que momento ou qual função seja jquery ou nativa do javascript posso usar para verificar se o post foi concluido e após isso dar um `scope.loading = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso esteja usando jQuery para fazer as chamadas Ajax ao servidor, voce pode usar os eventos [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) e [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) para executar a sua logica sempre que uma requisiçao Ajax seja iniciada ou finalizada.

Exemplo:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings){
    console.log(settings.type);
    if(settings.type == "POST"){
        console.log("Foi um POST que acabou.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Era realmente isso que eu tinha em mente Renato. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Caso você esteja usando jQuery,
pode adicionar um cabecário personalizado a todas as requisições Ajax, 
usando a seguinte sintaxe em script carregado logo após a carga do jQuery:

```
<script>
jQuery.ajaxSetup({headers: {"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest", "X-Ajax" : "1"}});
</script>
```

E você poderá ter acesso a estes valores no controller PHP através do acesso a `$_SERVER`

Comment: nesse caso para meu uso seria mais complexo já que utilizo a Jquery e o Angular. É uma aplicação em Java, mas todo o tratamento é feito no front-end. O Java é responsavél apenas pelos serviços. Mas obrigado pela a ajuda :)

Comment: Você poderá recuperar os valores no Java, pois isto é passado a cada requisição para o controller

Answer (score 1):

Caso esteja usando angularJS recomendo o uso do angular-block-ui, que faz sozinho o controle de "loading" nas requisições.

https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui

Comment: boa, vou dar uma olhada nele valeu!